# Modular exponentiation. Why all different?

Tags: mathematics

Why is it if we use 1 2 3 4 mod 5 and we take x^3 of this numbers, we come to: 1 3 2 4 (all numbers are different as you can see)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question does not appear to be about creation and solving of puzzles, within the scope defined in the help center.

Comment: I don't know if this question is right or wrong. Anyway, here are more numbers with the same property: http://oeis.org/A074243

Comment: @MichałWójcik Thank you. I still can't proof it :D

Answer (score 1):

Hint: using the Binomial Theorem we get
$$ x=5k => x^3 \equiv 0 \mod 5 $$
$$ x=5k+1 => x^3 \equiv 1 \mod 5 $$
$$ x=5k+2 => x^3 \equiv 8 \equiv 3 \mod 5 $$ 
$$ x=5k+3 => x^3 \equiv 27 \equiv 2 \mod 5 $$
$$ x=5k+4 => x^3 \equiv 64 \equiv 4 \mod 5 $$

Comment: (Does this question seem even remotely on-topic to you?)

Comment: Sorry but I didn't understand it. Is there an easier way to proof it?

Comment: @Rubio: surely the tag mathematics is correct, but you are right, it is more for the math.SE than the puzzle.SE.

Comment: @ThomasL Can you please help me?

Comment: @Jeck: does my hint help you? If not please tell me what to elaborate. Please note, this question might get closed as communicated by Rubio. It would be better if you ask this question in math.stackexchange.com as it is just mathematics and not puzzling.

Comment: @ThomasL I think there is an easier way with Euler's theorem, but I can't seem to find it.

Comment: @JackCoeler Doesn’t Euler’s Theorem require counting relative primes? ThomasL’s answer looks way simpler than having to do that.